# Object follow camera position in Threejs

Tags: javascript, three.js

Hi I'm doing a game that consist in first person shooter, the idea is that soldiers have to follow me and if they touch me i died, but the problem is in the rotation of y axis for soldiers they not all the time are looking me please your help...

My code for rotation:

```
 var diferenceX = controls.getObject().position.x - soldier.position.x;
 var diferenceZ = controls.getObject().position.z - soldier.position.z;

 if( diferenceX > 0 )
   if( diferenceZ > 0 )
     soldier.rotation.y = 2*Math.PI*Math.atan(diferenceZ/diferenceX);
   else
     soldier.rotation.y = Math.atan(diferenceX/diferenceZ);
 else if( diferenceZ > 0 )
   soldier.rotation.y = -3*Math.atan(diferenceZ/diferenceX)
 else
   soldier.rotation.y = Math.atan(diferenceX/diferenceZ);

 controls.getObject().position = my position
```

Comment: Your JS is almost unreadable. Please format it correctly, including indentation and curly braces.

Comment: I guess your logic is flawed because the `else` followed by an `if` gets combined as an `else if`. Use blocks `{}` !